# what is the best way to take user input in multiple step process of registration

Tags: django

I am developing an application using django framework- which has following.

model

```
class User:
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True )
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True )
class A
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True )
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True )
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True )
class B
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field4 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True )
    field5 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True )
    field6 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True )
class C
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field7 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True )
    field8 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True )
    field9 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True )
```

form

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    firstname = forms.CharField(label='', required=True)
    lastname = forms.CharField(label='', required=True)
    username = forms.CharField(label='', required=False)
        
    class Meta:
        fields = ("firstname", 
        "lastname", 
        "username",
        )
        model = models.User 

class AForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field1 = forms.CharField(label='', required=True)
    field2 = forms.CharField(label='', required=True)
    field3 = forms.CharField(label='', required=False)
        
    class Meta:
        fields = ("field1", 
        "field2", 
        "field3",
        )
        model = models.A 
        
class BForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field4 = forms.CharField(label='', required=True)
    field5 = forms.CharField(label='', required=True)
    field6 = forms.CharField(label='', required=False)
        
    class Meta:
        fields = ("field4", 
        "field5", 
        "field6",
        )
        model = models.B 
        
class CForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field7 = forms.CharField(label='', required=True)
    field8 = forms.CharField(label='', required=True)
    field9 = forms.CharField(label='', required=False)
        
    class Meta:
        fields = ("field7", 
        "field8", 
        "field9",
        )
        model = models.C
```

views

```
    def createuser(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
          form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, )
          if form.is_valid():
               userdata = form.save()
               return redirect('myapp:createA',userdata.id)
          else:
               return redirect('myapp:createuser')
     else:
          userform = UserForm()
          return render(request, 'user/userform.html', {'form':userform})
          
          
    def createA(request, id):
     user = User.objects.get(id=id)
     if request.method == 'POST':
          try:
               data_A = A.objects.get(A_id=id)
               form = AForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=data_A)
               if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    return redirect('myapp:createB',id)
               else:
                    return redirect('myapp:createA',id)
          except A.DoesNotExist as e:
               form = AForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
               if form.is_valid():     
                    value_A = form.save(commit=False)
                    value_A.user = user
                    value_A.save()
                    return redirect('myapp:createB',id)
                else:
                    return redirect('myapp:createA',id)
     else:
          try:
               data_A = A.objects.get(A_id=id)
               form = AForm(instance=data_A)
               return render(request, 'a/aform.html', {'form':form})
          except A.DoesNotExist as e:
               form = AForm()
               return render(request, 'a/aform.html', {'form':form})


    def createB(request, id):
     user = User.objects.get(id=id)
     if request.method == 'POST':
          try:
               data_B = B.objects.get(B_id=id)
               form = BForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=data_B)
               if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    return redirect('myapp:createC',id)
               else:
                    return redirect('myapp:createB',id)
          except B.DoesNotExist as e:
               form = BForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
               if form.is_valid():     
                    value_B = form.save(commit=False)
                    value_B.user = user
                    value_B.save()
                    return redirect('myapp:createC',id) 
                else:
                    return redirect('myapp:createB',id)
     else:
          try:
               data_B = B.objects.get(B_id=id)
               form = BForm(instance=data_B)
               return render(request, 'b/bform.html', {'form':form})
          except B.DoesNotExist as e:
               form = bForm()
               return render(request, 'b/bform.html', {'form':form})
               
               

    def createC(request, id):
     user = User.objects.get(id=id)
     if request.method == 'POST':
          try:
               data_C = C.objects.get(C_id=id)
               form = CForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=data_C)
               if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    return redirect('myapp:usersummary',id)
               else:
                    return redirect('myapp:createC',id)
          except C.DoesNotExist as e:
               form = CForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
               if form.is_valid():     
                    value_C = form.save(commit=False)
                    value_C.user = user
                    value_C.save()
                    return redirect('myapp:usersummary',id) 
                else:
                    return redirect('myapp:createC',id)
     else:
          try:
               data_C = C.objects.get(C_id=id)
               form = CForm(instance=data_C)
               return render(request, 'c/cform.html', {'form':form})
          except C.DoesNotExist as e:
               form = bForm()
               return render(request, 'b/bform.html', {'form':form})
               
def usersummary(request,id):

     try:
          userdata = User.objects.get(id=id)
          return render(request, 'summary/usersummary.html',{"user":userdata})
     except User.DoesNotExist as e:
          return redirect('/passport/account/dashboard/')
```

Now when signing up I have to take the user input save the data one by one
i.e. form1 = user, form2 = classA, form3 = classB, form4 = classC and so on.
What is the best approach in django to achieve this, considering that user can go to previous step - form and go to next step - form and there is no data lost. Also how can I implement this using django- class based views. The above piece of code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I know is using: https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#module-formtools.wizard.views

1. you won't have the user data splitted in many models, you can do it but after will be a mess update data for a user in many models.
2. using the wizard you can model your data user as you wish
3. then you have to create the forms for the wizard steps
4. create a view with the wizard specifying the forms to use
5. do something with the forms cleaned_data.

Using wizards you avoid boilerplate code that you won't have to maintain, use a standar way of doing it and also you can choose between session and cookies to save the data and don't loose it.

Wizards used to live in Django.

> This code used to live in Django proper -- in django.contrib.formtools -- but was separated into a standalone package in Django 1.8 to keep the framework's core clean.